# How to get unspent bitcoins using bitcoinj

Tags: bitcoinj, utxo

I'm trying to get unspent transaction using bitcoinj like [here](http://tbtc.blockr.io/api/v1/address/unspent/n1XZMMm3ikh97Mr8JVnnahfugad2DRcVrB?format=xml)
without using api calls. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoinj is only a library, but there is an experimental full verification mode that would allow this. https://bitcoinj.github.io/full-verification  It is important to note it is not intended for production use and almost certainly contains chain splitting bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Map<Sha256Hash, Transaction> unspentTxs = wallet.getTransactionPool(WalletTransaction.Pool.UNSPENT);
```